# Parsing Json in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am learning flutter and trying to parse a json which is array or json objects like this.

```
[
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
  },]
```

And here is my fetch function which fetches this data from server.

```
 fetch() async{

   var client = new http.Client();
  try {
  var uriResponse = await 
  client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos');
  if(uriResponse.statusCode == 200){

  var data = json.decode(uriResponse.body);//data is array of objects
  List<Photo> pics= data.map((Map<String,dynamic> model)=> Photo.fromJson(model)).toList();
  setState(() {
    photos = data;
    _isLoading = false;
  });
}
  } finally {
client.close();
  }
}
```

But the line ;

```
List<Photo> pics= data.map((Map<String,dynamic> model)=> Photo.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

gives me error that:

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '(Map<String, dynamic>, dynamic) => Photo' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'
```

Here is my Photo PODO class.

```
  class Photo {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  Photo({this.id, this.title,this.url, this.thumbnailUrl});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Photo(
      id: json['id'] as int,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumbnailUrl'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

What i am doing wrong in the above code? Thanx in advance !

Comment: Have you tried using [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable)?

Comment: For advanced JSON parsing, you can use [built_value](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart).

Comment: The best way use online json to dart pojo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901760/convert-json-into-pojo-object-similar-to-android-in-flutter/57661949#

Answer (score 2):

You can use [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io) it lets you copy in your JSON string and generates the Dart Objects

Answer (score 1):

In my project I have done like this and its working

```
pics = (data as List).map((model) => Photo.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
pics = data.map((i)=>Photo.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

You are receiving an **json array** and not **json object** from server

Comment: this gives error : : [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Photo>'

Comment: and when i changes it to dynamic then i cant access the Photo class variable

Answer (score 0):

try this if it didnt work make sure to print the the response body

```
Iterable<dynamic> l = json.decode(uriResponse.body);
List<Post> posts = l.map((model) => Post.fromJson(model)).toList();
```