# how to parse a Json that has inside it's body multi Childrens

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dart

i need to know please how to execute my code inside the Widgets like a text Widget.
i know that i will need a Future Bilder and for Example a ListView or a ListViewBuilder
but how can i exactly get all the urls inside every Child that the json Body has.
as you can see here in this json ,
or from here the full version of the json that i want to parse it and get all the urls from inside all the Childrens
[jsonUrl](http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?render=json&c=podcast)

```
{ "head": {    "title": "Podcasts",
    "status": "200"}, "body": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"text" : "Music", 
"children": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Schlager", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100000594&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000594" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Rádios da Metropolitana FM", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100002153&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100002153" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Hits Popular", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100000599&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000599" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Top 40 & Pop Music", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c57943&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c57943" },
] },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"text" : "Talk", 
"children": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "International Public Radio", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100001487&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100001487" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "History Podcasts", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100000897&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000897" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
] 
{ "head": {    "title": "Podcasts",
    "status": "200"}, "body": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"text" : "Music", 
"children": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Schlager", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100000594&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000594" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Rádios da Metropolitana FM", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100002153&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100002153" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Hits Popular", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100000599&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100000599" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "Top 40 & Pop Music", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c57943&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c57943" },
] },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"text" : "Talk", 
"children": [
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "one", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100001487&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c100001423" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
"type" : "link", 
"text" : "two", 
"URL" : "http://xx?id=c100000897&filter=p:topic", 
"guide_id" : "c1000008932" },
 { "element" : "outline", 
] }
] }
}
] }
```

i can get just the urls from inside a specific child, but i can't get all the urls those exist inside all the Childrens.
when i execute my code i get this error

```
I/flutter (11582): Exception: type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Iterable<dynamic>' of 'f'
```

here is my code and please help .
thanks in advance.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Future<List<Children>> fetchsprodcasts(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  await client.get("http://opml.radiotime.com/Browse.ashx?render=json&c=podcast", headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
  return compute(parseProdcasts,utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
}
List<Children> parseProdcasts(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody)['body'].map((item)=> item['children']).toList().expand((x) => x).toList();
  return parsed.map((m) => new Children.fromJson(m)).toList();
}
class Prodcasts {
  Head head;
  List<Body> body;

  Prodcasts({this.head, this.body});

  Prodcasts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    head = json['head'] != null ? new Head.fromJson(json['head']) : null;
    if (json['body'] != null) {
      body = new List<Body>();
      json['body'].forEach((v) {
        body.add(new Body.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.head != null) {
      data['head'] = this.head.toJson();
    }
    if (this.body != null) {
      data['body'] = this.body.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
class Head {
  String title;
  String status;

  Head({this.title, this.status});

  Head.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    title = json['title'];
    status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    return data;
  }
}
class Body {
  String element;
  String text;
  List<Children> children;

  Body({this.element, this.text, this.children});

  Body.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    element = json['element'];
    text = json['text'];
    if (json['children'] != null) {
      children = new List<Children>();
      json['children'].forEach((v) {
        children.add(new Children.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['element'] = this.element;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    if (this.children != null) {
      data['children'] = this.children.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
class Children {
  String element;
  String type;
  String text;
  String uRL;
  String guideId;

  Children({this.element, this.type, this.text, this.uRL, this.guideId});

  Children.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    element = json['element'];
    type = json['type'];
    text = json['text'];
    uRL = json['URL'];
    guideId = json['guide_id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['element'] = this.element;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    data['URL'] = this.uRL;
    data['guide_id'] = this.guideId;
    return data;
  }
}
void main() {
  runApp(ParseProdcastss());
}
class ParseProdcastss extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ParseProdcasts();
  }
}
class ParseProdcasts extends StatelessWidget {
  ParseProdcasts({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  FutureBuilder<List<Children>>(
      future: fetchsprodcasts(http.Client()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ProdcastsList(childrenList: snapshot.data) :Container(
          color: Colors.white,
              child: Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff193451),
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blueGrey),
        )),
            );
      },
    );
  }
}
class ProdcastsList extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Children> childrenList = []; // We assume that you filled this list with children.
  ProdcastsList({Key key, this.childrenList}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProdcastsListState createState() => _ProdcastsListState();
}
class _ProdcastsListState extends State<ProdcastsList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: widget.childrenList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ExpansionTile(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      ],
                      title: Text('${widget.childrenList[index].text}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.blueGrey),),
                      subtitle: Text(''),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

regards

Comment: no one can help ?, the json url exists, my code also, the error message,and i explained my issue so why no one wants help .
i think i will need like this solution, using for loop or foreach, to get all the childrens , but how can i do it , 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736381/json-parsing-in-dart-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You already have all data. You can do it like this:

```
class DyanmicList extends State<ListDisplay> {
  
  List<Children> childrenList = []; // We assume that you filled this list with children.

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Dynamic Demo"),),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
       
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder
              (
                itemCount: childrenList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                  return new Text(childrenList[Index]);
                }
            )
        )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

You can read [more](https://medium.com/@DakshHub/flutter-displaying-dynamic-contents-using-listview-builder-f2cedb1a19fb).

Comment: thanks for your help , please see the post one more time, i added the full code, but the length return null .

Comment: error message has been added, thanks again, may i ask you to try getting the urls from all the childrens if you have a time pls. and if you succeeded then can you pelase tell me how you did it