# How can I define a variable like JSON object in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, forms, save, fluttermap

What I am trying to do is creating a variable that can hold the following data:

```
questiion = { 'title': '',
            'description': '',
            'questionTitle': '',
            'option1Text': '',
            'option2Text': '',
            'option3Text': '',
            'option1Correctness': false,
            'option2Correctness': false,
            'option3Correctness': false,
            'questionNumber' : 1 }
```

Then I can get these values from forms and save the users input data into them like following:

```
          onSaved: (value) {
            question['title'] = value!;
          },
```

I don't know if there is any data type in flutter for doing that? I know there is `Map<>` but it can only consist 1 pair of `key:value`. Maybe I should create a nested Map? Or there is a better way?

Comment: This questions variable is already a Map<String, dynamic> and can do what it is you're asking. A Map can take very many pair values.

Comment: @DARTender: Yeah, I didn't know a `dynamic` variable can hold a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map<String,dynamic>` should be right way (if you don't want to create a class).

Like this:

```dart
    final question = <String, dynamic>{
      'title': '',
      'description': '',
      'questionTitle': '',
      'option1Text': '',
      'option2Text': '',
      'option3Text': '',
      'option1Correctness': false,
      'option2Correctness': false,
      'option3Correctness': false,
      'questionNumber': 1
    };

    print(question);
```

The print will give you this output:

```
{title: , description: , questionTitle: , option1Text: , option2Text: , option3Text: , option1Correctness: false, option2Correctness: false, option3Correctness: false, questionNumber: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go for a nested key-value map, or you can also keep everything in an object.

This ans might help you:
[Json parsing in dart (flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59736381/json-parsing-in-dart-flutter)