# How to convert a nested JSON into an Object

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I need to send an Object as body parameter to a Post request. My Object is being created from a nested Json and I can't get it working so far.

I've done this quite easy in JavaScript but I haven't found the way to do this in Dart/Flutter.

The "conventional" way I've done this before is as simple as:

```
var data = {
      "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
      "password": "123",
      "first_name": "qweqwe",
      "billing": {
        "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
        "phone": "321654978",
      },
      "shipping": {
        "first_name": "qweqwe",
      }
    }
```

By using the same structure in Dart/Flutter I get below error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

I've tried with `Map<String, dynamic>`, `Map<String, String>`, using a model for my data....

If I send the same Json but without `"billing"` and `"shipping"` (no nested Json) it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON into POJO (Object) similar to android in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901760/convert-json-into-pojo-object-similar-to-android-in-flutter)

Comment: The problem has most likely nothing to do with converting JSON back and forth. It seems more like a wrong payload structure the server does not accept.

Answer (score 4):

The sort answer if you want to upload your `data` object is to convert it to a string like so:

```
var jsonString = json.encode(data);
// upload jsonString as body to your server.
print("Json String is " + jsonString);

Map headers = {
  'Content-type' : 'application/json',
};

http.post("www.server.com/myPostEndpoint", body: jsonString, headers: headers);
```

Like discussed in the comments you may need to wrap the entire content in a `data` property. You may try this:

```
var payload = {   
    "data": {
       "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
       "password": "123",
       "first_name": "qweqwe",
       "billing": {
         "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
         "phone": "321654978",
       },
       "shipping": {
         "first_name": "qweqwe",
       }   
   } 
};

var jsonString = json.encode(payload); // upload jsonString as body to your server. print("Json String is " + jsonString);

Map headers = {   'Content-type': 'application/json', };

http.post("www.server.com/myPostEndpoint", body: jsonString, headers: headers);
```

**tl;dr**

Its always a good idea to create a Model. 
So this could be your `User` model:

```
class User {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String firstName;
  final Map<String, String> billing;
  final Map<String, String> shipping;

  User({this.email, this.password, this.firstName, this.billing, this.shipping});

  static User fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return User(
      email: json["email"],
      password: json["password"],
      firstName: json["first_name"],
      billing: json["billing"],
      shipping: json["shipping"],
    );
  }

}
```

It has a static constructor which is handy for creating an instance of this `User` from a piece of decoded json like you have.

Now you can go ahead and use this model in your code like so:

```
var data = {
  "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
  "password": "123",
  "first_name": "qweqwe",
  "billing": {
    "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
    "phone": "321654978",
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "qweqwe",
  }
};


var user = User.fromJson(data);

print("Users Email is ${user.billing["email"]}");
```

It would be even cleaner to also create models for both `Billing` and maybe also `Shipping`.

Here is a complete example which also includes the `toJson()` methods to generate Json from a parsed model:

```
class User {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String firstName;
  final Billing billing;
  final Shipping shipping;

  User({this.email, this.password, this.firstName, this.billing, this.shipping});

  static User fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return User(
      email: json["email"],
      password: json["password"],
      firstName: json["first_name"],
      billing: Billing.fromJson(json["billing"]),
      shipping: Shipping.fromJson(json["shipping"]),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'email': email, 'password': password, 'first_name': firstName, 'billing': billing.toJson(), 'shipping': shipping.toJson()};
}

class Billing {
  final String email;
  final String phone;

  Billing({this.email, this.phone});

  static Billing fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Billing(email: json["email"], phone: json["phone"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'email': email, 'phone': phone};
}

class Shipping {
  final String name;

  Shipping({
    this.name,
  });

  static Shipping fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return Shipping(
      name: json["first_name"],
    );
  }


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'name': name};
}
```

And this is how you could use it:

```
var data = {
  "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
  "password": "123",
  "first_name": "qweqwe",
  "billing": {
    "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
    "phone": "321654978",
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "qweqwe",
  }
};


var user = User.fromJson(data);

print("Users Email is ${user.billing.email}");
print("Shipping name is ${user.shipping.name}");

var jsonString = json.encode(user.toJson()); // upload this as body to your server.
print("Json String is " + jsonString);
```

Comment: When I use the model as a parameter I get `Invalid request body "Instance of 'User'"`
What I need is to be able to send the object as body parameter, not just parse it...
I'm stuck for a few days on this... I'm out of ideas right now

Comment: How do you use it as a parameter?

Comment: In my question says that I need this to send the "converted" Json as parameter for a Http Post request

Comment: Oh yes I am sorry. Must have misunderstood your question. Please take a look at my edit. It now has incorporated the generation of a json string for your post body.

Comment: Look at the very top of my answer. Maybe this is what you are searching for.

Comment: I forgot to mention that every time I've tried with json.encode I get no error from Dart/Flutter but the error comes from my API response. `{code: rest_missing_callback_param, message: Parámetro(s) que falta(n): email, password, data: {status: 400, params: [email, password]}}`

Comment: Well looks like your server is expecting a different json structure. Can you post some server code that is parsing your incoming Post request?

Comment: I'm just trying to send this data using a WooCommerce API. It's quite known. I've done this before, without any issues, in JavaScript where I just send the data "as is". No conversion...

Comment: WooCommerce is not happy with your payload. The only thing I can think of is that if you do it in JS you may wrap the entire object within a data object.

Comment: Once again. Please take a look at the top of my answer. I've edited it once more.

Comment: There's no changes when wrapping within a data object. I've already tested adding headers and nothing. I just don't know what else to try. It seems like Google has some minor fixes to do regarding this topic. This should be as simple as just sending the Json Object as is...

Comment: I believe your problem is not related to Dart or Flutter. The error you are seeing is clearly an indication that your WooCommerce instance is not happy with the structure of your payload. I suggest you start a new Topic in a WooCommerce section of StackOverflow.

Comment: I made the exact same app in Ionic and it works fine and I did exactly what I did. I just don't know why I'm struggling with this in Flutter as this should be a straightforward process...

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers might be (greatly) over-complicating this. Regardless of which language you're using, to send JSON to a server, you'll need to send the data as a *string*, with an `application/json` content type. `json.encode` handles nested Maps already, so you don't need to do anything special... At all:

```dart
// Replace the "..." with the rest of your data.
var data = {"email": "qwe@qwe.com", "password": "123", ...}

// `asJson` is a String.
var asJson = json.encode(data);

// Send it
var response = await client.post('example.com/...', body: asJson, headers: {'content-type', 'application/json'});
```

That's all you need to do. There's not really a need to make an entire `User` class with `fromJson`, `toJson`, etc.

As for this error - `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`, I have no idea what the *exact* cause, as you didn't provide the relevant code, but it's clear that at some point, you gave Dart a Map where it was expecting a String. Like you said, you've tried `Map<String, dynamic>` and `Map<String, String`, but what was really necessary was a `String`.

If you're not already using the Dart analyzer (usually in an IDE plugin), this is the kind of error it can easily catch.

Hope this helped!

**TLDR:** Call `json.encode(data)` to get a `String`, and then send that `String`, along with an `application/json` content type, to the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Do you get a runtime error, or does the server itself send you an error? There's not really a way to know if you don't say...

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, there should be commas only between values.

```
var data = {
  "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
  "password": "123",
  "first_name": "qweqwe",
  "billing": {
    "email": "qwe@qwe.com",
    "phone": "321654978"
  },
  "shipping": {
    "first_name": "qweqwe"
  }
}
```

Here i removed commas at the end  of the fields "phone" and "first_name".