# how to parse complex json in flutter

Tags: arrays, json, list, dart, flutter

I have trouble getting data from a complex json, below is the json in the request.

```
{
   "results":{
      "TotalRecordCount":"1",
      "Records":[
         {
            "code":"PCK_34333338365C93E2D50DB9C",
            "address":"1 AV KHEIREDDINE PACHA Imm Pacha centre BLOC B tunis Tunis 1000",
            "contact_phone":"99608258"
         }
      ],
      "Result":"OK"
   }
}
```

Below is the model I made.

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Pickup {
  String status;
  List message;
  //Map<String ,dynamic> results;
  Results results;
  Pickup(
    {this.status,
     this.message,
     this.results,
  });
  factory Pickup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Pickup(
             status: json["status"] as String,
             results: Results.fromJson(json["results"]),

           );
  }
}

class Results {
  String TotalRecordCount;
  records Records;

  Results({this.TotalRecordCount,this.Records});

  factory Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Results(
    TotalRecordCount: json["TotalRecordCount"],
    Records:records.fromJson(json["Records"]),

    );
  }
}

class records{
  String code;
  String address;
  String contact_phone;

  records({
    this.code,
    this.address,
    this.contact_phone
  });

  factory records.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return records(
      code: json["code"],
      address: json["address"],
      contact_phone: json["contact_phone"],
    );
  }
}
```

Now Im trying to parse the records to get the code or address and print it.

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(response.body);
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  var da=Pickup.fromJson(responseJson);
  Results dat=da.results;
  records data=dat.Records;
  print(data.address);
}
```

The response.body is working fine but when I try to parse results or records I got 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' error

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries

Comment: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: The best way use online Json to dart pojo converter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901760/convert-json-into-pojo-object-similar-to-android-in-flutter/57661949#

Answer (score 24):

I will definitely recommend you this website json to dart [App Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/) just don't forget to select Dart in the right side.

You just put your json in la left and in will give you something like this:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final pickUp = pickUpFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

PickUp pickUpFromJson(String str) => PickUp.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String pickUpToJson(PickUp data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class PickUp {
    Results results;

    PickUp({
        this.results,
    });

    factory PickUp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new PickUp(
        results: Results.fromJson(json["results"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "results": results.toJson(),
    };
}

class Results {
    String totalRecordCount;
    List<Record> records;
    String result;

    Results({
        this.totalRecordCount,
        this.records,
        this.result,
    });

    factory Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Results(
        totalRecordCount: json["TotalRecordCount"],
        records: new List<Record>.from(json["Records"].map((x) => Record.fromJson(x))),
        result: json["Result"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "TotalRecordCount": totalRecordCount,
        "Records": new List<dynamic>.from(records.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "Result": result,
    };
}

class Record {
    String code;
    String address;
    String contactPhone;

    Record({
        this.code,
        this.address,
        this.contactPhone,
    });

    factory Record.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Record(
        code: json["code"],
        address: json["address"],
        contactPhone: json["contact_phone"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "code": code,
        "address": address,
        "contact_phone": contactPhone,
    };
}
```

at the beginning it will tell you how you can use it.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final pickUp = pickUpFromJson(jsonString);
```

So when you call it in you code its gonna be something like this.

```
  Future<Pickup> getPickup() async {
    var response = await http.get(url);
    return pickUpFromJson(response.body);
  }
```

This code could be call for a FutureBuilder for example or wherever you set the code to wait for a future.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries

Specifically the part that uses [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "results":{
      "TotalRecordCount":"1",
      "Records":[
         {
            "code":"PCK_34333338365C93E2D50DB9C",
            "address":"1 AV KHEIREDDINE PACHA Imm Pacha centre BLOC B tunis Tunis 1000",
            "contact_phone":"99608258"
         }
      ],
      "Result":"OK"
   }
}
```

The above JSON file consists of a list of "Records" within it hence making it a complex JSON. Below are the amendments I would like to contribute to the code -

```
class Pickup {
  String status;
  List message;
  //Map<String ,dynamic> results;
  Results results;
  Pickup(
    {this.status,
     this.message,
     this.results,
  });
  factory Pickup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Pickup(
             status: json["status"] as String,
             results: Results.fromJson(json["results"]),

           );
  }
}
class Results {
  String TotalRecordCount;
  records Records;

  Results({this.TotalRecordCount,this.Records});



    factory Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        //since records is a list hence it is parsed separately by creating a 
        //list out of it.  
    



       listOfRecords = (json["Records"] as List)
      .map((i) => records.fromJson(i))
      .toList();


 
    return Results(
    TotalRecordCount: json["TotalRecordCount"],
    Records:listOfRecords //now the list is used here directly
),

    );
  }
}

class records{
  String code;
  String address;
  String contact_phone;

  records({
    this.code,
    this.address,
    this.contact_phone
  });

  factory records.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return records(
      code: json["code"],
      address: json["address"],
      contact_phone: json["contact_phone"],
    );
  }
```

At last, we can use this wherever it is required like this -

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(response.body);
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  var da = Pickup.fromJson(responseJson);
  Results dat = da.results;
  records data = dat.Records;
  print(data[0].address);  //since records was a list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a case, only one class is enough.
An example of how this can be done.

```dart
import 'package:fast_json/fast_json_selector.dart' as parser;

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final records = _parseRecords(_data);
  print('Found: ${records.length} records(s).');
  print(records.map((e) => e.code).join('\n'));
}

const _data = '''
{
   "results":{
      "TotalRecordCount":"1",
      "Records":[
         {
            "code":"PCK_34333338365C93E2D50DB9C",
            "address":"1 AV KHEIREDDINE PACHA Imm Pacha centre BLOC B tunis Tunis 1000",
            "contact_phone":"99608258"
         }
      ],
      "Result":"OK"
   }
}''';

List<Record> _parseRecords(String source) {
  // Path to Record
  // Map => 'results' => Map => 'records' => List => list index => Map (Record)
  final level = '{} results {} records [] 0 {}'.split(' ').length;
  final records = <Record>[];
  void select(parser.JsonSelectorEvent event) {
    if (event.levels.length == level) {
      final record = Record.fromJson(event.lastValue as Map);
      records.add(record);
      // Freeing the memory because it is no longer needed
      event.lastValue = null;
    }
  }

  parser.parse(source, select: select);
  return records;
}

class Record {
  String code;
  String address;
  String contact_phone;

  Record({
    required this.code,
    required this.address,
    required this.contact_phone,
  });

  factory Record.fromJson(Map json) {
    return Record(
      code: json["code"] as String,
      address: json["address"] as String,
      contact_phone: json["contact_phone"] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Found: 1 records(s).
PCK_34333338365C93E2D50DB9C
```