# How to get data from nested map api in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

**Api Response**

```
{
"IsError": "E",
"RespMessage": {
    "voter": {
        "name": "নবীর হোসেন",
        "nameEn": "Nobir Hossain",
        "father": "আব্দুর রাজ্জাক",
        "mother": "নাজমা বেগম",
        "gender": "male",
        "spouse": null,
        "dob": "01/01/1990",
        "permanentAddress": "বাসা/হোল্ডিং: , গ্রাম/রাস্তা: বীর সগুনা, , ডাকঘর: চর সগুনা-2010, মেলান্দহ, জামালপুর",
        "presentAddress": "বাসা/হোল্ডিং: , গ্রাম/রাস্তা: বীর সগুনা, ঘোষের পাড়া, ডাকঘর: চর সগুনা-2010, মেলান্দহ, জামালপুর",
        "photo": "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",
        "fatherEn": null,
        "motherEn": null,
        "spouseEn": null,
        "permanentAddressEn": null,
        "presentAddressEn": null
    },
    "passKyc": "yes",
    "errorCode": null
},
"ekyc_id": 110
}
```

When I fetch data it has shown me

> String type can't subtype of `Map<String, dynamic>

This is my fetch json decoded code

```
Future<NidResponseModel> fetchNidAccessData(
  NidAccessBody nidAccessBody) async {
var url = '';
final Response response = await Dio().post(
  Uri.encodeFull(url),
  data: json.encode(nidAccessBody.toJson()),
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map<String, dynamic> jsonString = jsonDecode(response.data);
  print(jsonString);
  return NidResponseModel.fromJson(jsonString);
} else {
  return null;
}
}
```

What am I missing? please rectify to do it correct way.

Comment: please share your code. May be you missed to decode your response

Comment: Future<NidResponseModel> fetchNidAccessData(
      NidAccessBody nidAccessBody) async {
    var url = '';
    final Response response = await Dio().post(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      data: json.encode(nidAccessBody.toJson()),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonString = jsonDecode(response.data);
      print(jsonString);
      return NidResponseModel.fromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

json is basically just a String coming from API.
You should first decode it to Map, so Dart can read its fiels.

```
Map<String, dynamic> decodedResposeAsMap = jsonDecode(apiResponse);
```

check here: [json serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#use-manual-serialization-for-smaller-projects)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56716530/13840311) when you want to parse complex json response.

Basically you have to create Class that will get data from very first level of your json response. In your case is

> "IsError", "RespMessage", and "ekyc_id"

and then you have to define the type for each object. And where the RespMessage contains object, you should create another class for that and do more parsing.

then you have to provide factory:

```
factory ObjectClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ObjectClass(
        someField: json['some_field'],
        anotherField: json['another_field']);
}
```

and for parsing you need to store it to map object:

```
Map<String, dynamic> mappedResponse = jsonDecode(response);
```

and do parsing with:

```
SomeClass.fromJson(mappedResponse);
```

Comment: @Dharman I was do the same thing that you are mention above but not work such this complex json response but it works in simple json response. can i more discuss with you?

Comment: @saiful.2396 I didn't write this answer. Please pay attention to who you ping. And no, Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum. If the answer didn't solve your problem consider clarifying your question.